# Getting page numbers while paginating wordpress posts page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to create some navigation with pictures of circles side by side for a posts page in Wordpress. Basically when it's the active page it needs to be a white circle and when it's not it needs to be a darker circle.

I've got them all to display darker circles easy enough but am struggling with getting the active page. Simply changing the a:active css doesn't work.

Is there a way to get the page number while paginating so I can give the links a different class e.g. activeCircle, when it is the active page. I've got the rest of the code figured out, just need an accurate way of getting the page I'm on.

Have tried $_GET from the super global and $page so far which I've seen other people use. Neither seem to output anything.

Code:

```
<div id="nav_numbers">
        <?php

        for($i = 1; $i <= (ceil(wp_count_posts()->publish / get_option('posts_per_page'))); $i++){

            $class = ($page == $i)?'class="activeDot"':'';

            ?>
            <a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?> /news/latest-news/page/<?= $i;?>/" <?=$class;?> >&nbsp;</a>
            <?php
        } ?>
</div>
```

The $page is the bit that doesn't work.

Comment: could you please give the pagination code?

Comment: inside `for` loop what it the output array of `$page`

Comment: Just tried echo $page inside the loop and it came out with nothing :/

Comment: this is the problem. $page should give the current page number. if it matched with the page number inside the loop would add activeDot class to <a>

Comment: Don't quite understand you. The $page outputs nothing....even inside the loop. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit modification:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$segments = explode('/', $url);
$current_page_number = end($segments);

<div id="nav_numbers">
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= (ceil(wp_count_posts()->publish / get_option('posts_per_page'))); $i++) : ?>
        <?php $class = if($current_page_number == $i ? 'active' : '' ) ?>
        <a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>/news/latest-news/page/<?=$i?>/" class="<?=$class?>">&nbsp;</a>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) Funnily enough I figured out the answer about 2 seconds before you posted. Can't answer my own question apparently for another 3 hours, but it was $paged not $page and it needed to be passed into the global of the function as well. Yours would work to so will mark it as the answer.